# Magento Rest API - Add Customer address

Tags: json, xml, rest, magento, magento-1.9

Most of Magento rest api methods works fine for me except **POST /customers/:customer_id/addresses**.

I get following error:

```
    <error>
      <data_item>
        <code>400</code>
        <message>"Street Address" is a required value.</message>
      </data_item>
      <data_item>
        <code>400</code>
        <message>Resource data pre-validation error.</message>
      </data_item>
    </error>
```

Error is clear saying address line is missing but I don't find anything wrong in my json request. I just converted the example XML request data from their docs into json and submitting in request body.

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/rest/Resources/resource_customer_addresses.html#RESTAPI-Resource-CustomerAddresses-HTTPMethod-POST-customers--customerid-addresses

Here is my json request data:

```
{
    "firstname": "Johny",
    "lastname": "Doe",
    "city": "PA",
    "region": "Palau",
    "postcode": "19103",
    "country_id": "US",
    "telephone": "611-634-1181",
    "street": {
      "data_item": [
        "2354 Jody Road Philadelphia",
        "844 Jefferson Street; 4510 Willis Avenue"
      ]
    }
  }
```

Please advise if anything wrong in above request.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, this is what worked for me (maybe their docs needs to update).

```
{
"firstname": "Johny",
"lastname": "Doe",
"city": "PA",
"region": "Palau",
"postcode": "19103",
"country_id": "US",
"telephone": "611-634-1181",
"street": 
   [
    "2354 Jody Road Philadelphia",
    "844 Jefferson Street; 4510 Willis Avenue"
  ]
```

}